# express res not working after DB connection

Tags: node.js, express

I try to connect the DB with Node.js. If I fire the script from console, all seems fine. But accessing from browser, response stops when connecting

From console, I get
inside contest
Example all listening on port 3000!
Connected Con!

From browser, I get
Hello World!inside restest

Since the the "listening..." message was before "Connected" in console version, I thought that in browser version, maybe the system got res.end() before it got connected to DB. Thus, I moved the res.end() from end of app.get -function to end of restest -function, and put a send()- to original place just in case. But that was not the reason as I still cannot get the "Connected Res!" -message.

```
var http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "login",
  password: "psw",
  database: "db"
});

function restest(req, res) {
    res.write("inside restest");

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write("Connected Res!");
        res.end();
    });
}

function contest() {
    console.log("inside contest");

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected Con!");
    });
}

contest();

app.get('/nodejs/', function(req, res) { 
    res.write('Hello World!');
    restest(req,res);
    res.send("this should not print out");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

No error messages, it just stops responses after writing "inside restest"

Comment: The connection is probably already there when you hit `restest`.  Is the error occuring from inside `restest`?

Comment: While testing further, I noticed the same: connection was already there when entering restest (actually, changed throw err -> res.write -version allowed me to see error from that). So I commented out the contest-fucntion with it's call, but got the original result. (without error this time thogh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mixing up some sync/async concepts.

Try something like this maybe it helps:

```
function restest(req, res, next) {
    res.write('inside restest');

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('Connected Res!');
        next();
    });
}

function contest(req, res, next) {
    console.log('inside contest');

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Connected Con!');
        next();
    });
}

app.get('/nodejs/', [contest, restest],function(req, res) { 
    res.write('Hello World!');
    restest(req,res);
});
```

Comment: After clearing out the error from second connection call (see comment in original question) and having still similar result, I tried it this way, and got the Connected Res!, but since was looking a way to call restest after the hello world, was still a problem (still seemed stopping after inside restest. But you are right in that the problem was about sunc/async -concept, as also @Bhaskar stated out. 
I got it working when doing it this example code's way: [link](https://codeforgeek.com/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

So, here what's happening is that: Once the `/nodejs` api is called it will write the `Hello World!` text and then it will go to `restest` function and it will write `inside restest` and then it will start connecting to the DB asynchronously as `DB connect` is an asynchrous function and it will come back to the `restest` function and it will send the response with `res.send("this should not print out");`. So, after this the `res` is no more accessible inside the `DB connect` function.